# Yamaha AG06 USB output is too low on MacBook Pro

Tags: audio-recording, mixing, mixer, usb, macbook-pro

For voice recording for webcasts, I am using the following setup:

- Rode Procaster microphone
- Yamaha AG06 mixing console

The Procaster is connected via XLR (without phantom power) to the mixing console. Input gain is at 6/10, volume for this channel is 10/10. The Yamaha AG06 again is connected to my MacBook Pro via USB.

Additionally, I have connected a pair of headphones to the monitoring output of the mixing console. The headphone volume is at 5/10.

The volume in the headphones is pretty good, everything is clear and loud, and there is no noise. In contrast to that, the volume at my MacBook Pro (I'm recording using QuickTime) is pretty low. When playing back video you have to set the volume of the MacBook Pro to the loudest option to hear things well.

Using the audio settings of macOS, I can not adjust the input gain of the USB port.

What am I doing wrong here?

PS: The problem is not the microphone, because if I also connect a Roland TR-8, its output is also pretty silent when recording over USB, but very well and loud in the headphones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the problem: I had enabled the built-in compressor of the mixing console, but it was configured not compress the signal enough. Once you change this using the software provided by Yamaha, everything is fine